# PL/SQL with single quotes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have that in a PL/SQL:

```
PROGRAMAS CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (256) := '''PILOTDAN''';
```

and that query doesn't work:

```
select * form table where id_programa IN (PROGRAMAS);
```

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: What data are you expecting in that column? `PILOTDAN` or `'PILOTDAN'` - should the column value itself contain the quotes?

Comment: You don't need to put your VARCHAR2 constant into quotes. Anyway, your `IN` statement won't work for more values than 1 (without using _dynamic SQL_), so you could just change it to the equation mark `=`.

Comment: This isn't related to the single quotes. [You simply cannot use a PL/SQL package constant in a SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178830/how-to-use-a-package-constant-in-sql-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use an extra `'`character in your constant string.

Try this:

```
PROGRAMAS CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (256) := 'PILOTDAN';

select * form table where id_programa IN ( PROGRAMAS );
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you it works, but whwne I put two values doesn't work: PROGRAMAS CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (256) := 'PILOTDAN , LVANGU01';

select * form table where id_programa IN ( PROGRAMAS );