# Oracle procedure CALL with package's constant

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Let's assume simple scenario like below:

```
CALL DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA(
   schemaurl      => 'non_existing_schemaurl',
   delete_option  => DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETE_INVALIDATE);
-- ORA-06553: PLS-221: 'DELETE_INVALIDATE' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

Meanwhile when providing integer value or running inside PL/SQL block the error does not occur:

```
-- 1)
CALL DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA(
   schemaurl      => 'non_existing_schemaurl',
   delete_option  => 2);

-- 2)
BEGIN
DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA(
   schemaurl      => 'non_existing_schemaurl',
   delete_option  => DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETE_INVALIDATE);
END;
/
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c605772a1c137703aada3f9dae9ed863)**

Is it possible to use `DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.<constant>` combined with `CALL`(searching for credible/official source)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a package constant in SQL SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178830/how-to-use-a-package-constant-in-sql-select-statement)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CALL.html):

> Use the CALL statement to execute a routine (a standalone procedure or
>   function, or a procedure or function defined within a type or package)
>   from within SQL.

The key is the last two words - *within SQL*.  It's easy to think of `CALL` as similar to the SQL*Plus command `EXEC`, but `CALL` runs in a SQL context while `EXEC` runs in a PL/SQL context.

PL/SQL package variables cannot be used in SQL statements (except for PL/SQL WITH functions, but that feature doesn't work in this context).  Unfortunately I can't find an authoritative source for that claim (which is why this is a Wiki answer; hopefully someone else can add that source and then remove this sentence.)

Answer (score -1):

The way you are trying to call is possible only in any named or unnamed block of pl/sql.
To call it independently, you need to pass the arguments only.

```
CALL DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA('none_existing_schemaurl','DELETE_INVALIDATE');
```

Comment: The proposed `CALL DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA('none_existing_schemaurl','DELETE_INVALIDATE');` does not work. [Counterexample demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a7112f86cc5560066bba266471d9b764)